# execute java button in a jar from command line

Tags: java, button, jar, cmd, void

I have a jar that I want just to get the output from that program. When we execute the jar, that will open a window and there are three button in that window. I need to click the second button, and after we click that button, it will open a new window and I need click another button there that open an file dialog, we need to choose a file and then click open. That is the program will produce the output. But, I want it to execute it without open the program jar  interface, just use commandline like

```
java -cp test.jar click_button1 click_button2(file.txt)
```

so the user don't need to see the interface, the program just running on the backside.

Please advise and help. thank you.

Comment: *"I have a jar that I want just to get the output from that program."* Check if it accepts a command line parameter specifying the file name.  That ***might*** allow the app. to do what it does when the button is clicked, but without showing the GUI.  Failing that you need to get the authors of the Jar to provide a version of the app. that is compatible with being run from the command line.  BTW - Does the GUI always appear at the exact same location/size on screen?

Comment: is that jar your own program?

Comment: You should try to make a java command line application that uses the jar. If the application developer hasn't made protected classes, chances are you can access the functionality through your code.

Comment: No, it's not my program, I want to use it as library, this jar is not open source, and there's no documentation about the void in there. So confusing :(

Comment: 1) To notify someone of a comment add @NameOfPerson 2) *Does the GUI always appear at the exact same location/size on screen?*  I cannot help you if you ignore my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is difficult to understand.

But if you are looking for a way to send commands to the commandline from Java, you can use Runtime in Java:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#getRuntime%28%29

```
Runtime cmd = Runtime.getRuntime();
cmd.exec("java -cp test.jar click_button1 click_button2(file.txt)");
```